# Global NPM package installed but command not found

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file, npm, package

I have globally installed two npm packages ["download"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download) and ["enigmavirtualbox"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enigmavirtualbox) via command line:

`npm install -g download` and
`npm install -g engimavirtualbox`

I'm trying to use them in a batch file to bundle a single .exe file from my node project. For both, the commands `npm list -g <packagename>` yield the respective version output, independent of the present working directory.

However, inside my batch script the commands "download" and "enigmavirtualbox" cannot be found.

Running `npm root -g` yields `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and looking inside that folder I can see that folders for both packages are present.

What I have tried:

- Changing `npm root` as described [here](http://blog.webbb.be/command-not-found-node-npm/)
- Uninstall and reinstall packages
- Add env. variable NODE_PATH to point to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
- Add `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` to PATH env. variable

The same setup works on my second computer (both run Win7 64bit). Is something wrong with my node installation, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The executable binaries and .cmd files end up in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` (minus the `node_modules` at the end) so adding that path to the PATH env. variable fixed the issue.

With environment variables, the path can be abbreviated: `%appdata\npm`.

Comment: That works, although maybe it would be better to use a wildcard: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`. That line has to go before any npm, node or nodejs paths in your PATH env variable, so that npm can find your global packages appropriately.

Comment: I have created my own node package.json and ran `npm install -g` from there (I haven't published it as I need it to stay private). This puts the package data and dependencies in `%appdata%\npm\node_modules` but there's no `.cmd` file where you said.

Comment: what's the path for mac ?

Comment: The entry is in my path variable gulp can be found bug gulp-sass not. Not working for me.

Comment: Funny enough that variable is set and added correctly, still not found. The Answer of Mr.Noob did it for me (Windows 10).

Answer (score 24):

If the above method does not work then use this command to explicitly set the path

```
npm config set prefix c:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

Comment: This also works if you don't have admin privileges, which is nice...

Answer (score 5):

Just run this command

```
SET PATH=%AppData%\npm;%PATH%
```

Comment: Or if you want to add it to your PowerShell profile: `$env:Path = "$env:appdata\npm;$env:Path"`

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Add `%APPDATA%\npm` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Long answer:

npm saves the `.cmd` file which gets executed when you execute a command from a npm package (and everything is working as it should) in the `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm` directory (`%username%` is the username of the current user).


Because userprofiles are not necessarily inside of `C:\Users` it's better to use a variable like `%userprofile%` which points to the userprofile of the current user or `%APPDATA%` which points to `AppData\Roaming` inside of the userprofile of the current user.

By adding `%APPDATA%\npm` to the `PATH` env. variable windows automatically searches there for a file with the name you entered as a command if the current directory doesn't contain a file with that name.


For every command there is also a file without a suffix in the npm folder which is a bash script and wont work on Windows (if you don't use bash) but Windows finds the `.cmd` file first so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Set your `PATH` environment variable to `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here more info about this topic :  https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/npm-tricks-part-1-get-list-of-globally-installed-packages-39a240347ef0

List of packages which have been install globally

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

Comment: He asked for "command not found" not for listing the installed packages

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's still having issues with missing commands. I have been dealing with this for a couple weeks and all but abandoned hope developing on windows. Then ran `npm config list` and found this:

```
; userconfig C:\Users\deane\.npmrc
bin-links = false
```

Need to change that to true. Even uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't help because it retains your .npmrc file.

Answer (score 0):

in order to use `npm install -g package-name` on windows, we need to configure the env variable as mentioned above. but if you don't want to configure the env variable then you can use yarn. if you have installed yarn then run

> yarn global add package-name

if you haven't installed yarn then you can install from here
[Install Yarn on Windows via MSI Installer](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/yarn-windows)