# npm update -g 1.5.0 equals errors

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

Hi I have seen a couple of these posts and none are really working for me, as soon as I install npm or update it shows these errors.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
```

and when I want to install or add anything from ionic it show this.

```
'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried `npm clear cache` and reinstalling ionic but still does not worked.
Also this only happened after updating npm, thank you.

Comment: The clue seems to be `npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com`, which sounds like you configured an improper proxy server address.

Comment: I have check my proxy settings are disabled, but I am not even exposed to be on a proxy.. I tried this from one article: 'npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080' @robertklep

Comment: If you don't need to use a proxy, you shouldn't configure npm to use one, which you did. So remove both proxy settings (`npm config delete proxy; npm config delete https-proxy`) and try again.

Comment: that resolved the proxy issue thanks but it still shows  'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. when adding a new project or installing ionic @robertklep

Comment: Perhaps the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955217/global-npm-package-installed-but-command-not-found) will help you with that.