# Cannot install my own npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've been developing a later-to-be-release Open Source project with Node as a CLI tool. The CLI itself works great I only need to test if it works while on another project, so for that I installed the projects globally  `npm install -g` without errors, but for the life of me I can't use the CLI.

I get the following error:

[image: node command not working]

The odd thing is that the directory and file does exist in the global npm folder:

[image: directory exists]

This is the project's `package.json`:

[image: package.json]

Am I not understanding how making a npm/node CLI works? What I'm missing?

**EDIT 1:**

This is my index.js file:

[image: index.js file]

And this is the commander.js file:
[image: command.js file]

**EDIT 2:**

After creating a test project as @AngYC suggested I could use the test cli successfully, while inspecting the difference I found this. Inside `C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Roaming\npm` the .cmd of both projects are quite different:

[image]

**EDIT 3 (Solution):**

After fiddling around I found out that the file that really needed the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env node`) was only `index.js` file and not the `commander.js` one. Removing the shebang in that file solved the problem

Comment: **Edit:** You might need to set your PATH environment variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955217/global-npm-package-installed-but-command-not-found

Comment: I already have npm in the path so its not that, but tried anyways, still the same :/

Comment: I know it's probably not this but maybe try `./index.js` instead of `index.js` for your `bin` mapping?

Comment: same outcome sadly :/ @nem035

Comment: Try creating a new project with only one index.js file and set it as bin main file (that print `Hello World`), then troubleshoot from it, I don't have a Windows machine to try now

Comment: @AngYC the test project works as a global command, I will post an update of something I found while inspecting

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to `link` your local package to your global executable list.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

All you have to do is run `npm link` in the folder you got your tool and it should make the command available globally.

Comment: tested `npm link`, it does **not (edited)** change the outcome

Comment: So it worked? If it did please consider marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: OMG sorry it as a typo **it does not**

Comment: haha ok I thought so. That would mean your node install is broken. Likely something to do with permissions but I got no clue about windows systems sorry.

Comment: `npm ERR! link should never be --global.` @Dominik

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall `cli` run `npm rm -g cli` or `sudo npm rm -g cli`. Then you run: `npm install cli -g`

If the problem persist, you might want to remove you npm package globally, probably there might be some conflicting things running.

Type this: `%appdata%` (either in explorer, run prompt, or start menu).

You can simply remove all globally installed npm packages by deleting the contents of:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Then you might also want to clear all the your cache run `npm cache clear` or `npm cache clear --force` as the case might be.

Then you reinstall all your packages that were install globally again.

If problem still persist, check this:

When you run `npm root -g`, it yields `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, or even, you should check your path maybe the executable binaries and `.cmd` files end up in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` instead of `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, you will need to add that path to the PATH env. variable.

I hope this resolves your issue.