# AndroidJs not recognize as command

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would to create a simple and basic html app for android using the androidjs framework: https://android-js.github.io/

I tried to follow some tutorial, i installed the builder with npm i g androidjs-builder, but when i make `androidjs init` or `androidjs --help` it returns command not found.

I tried also to install it locally, but nothing. In the npm list -g there is the framework correctly installed. How can i do? I can't find anything
From windows 10 i'm trying.

THank you

Comment: Likely a problem with your PATH. See here for OS specific fixes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found

Comment: I'm on windows 10 not on linux, and in my Path i have the both npm and nodejs path, and also the node_modules/bin path

Comment: you can follow the following to fix this error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43473654/8487165