# Netlify is not being recognized in Terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, netlify

I have done npm *install netlify-cli -g* and this is successfully installed. I get the following response:

> > npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues.
> >     Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
> >     C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\ntl ->
> >     C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netlify-cli\bin\run
> >     C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\netlify ->
> >     C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netlify-cli\bin\run
> >
> > netlify-cli@2.36.0 postinstall C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netlify-cli
> >     node ./scripts/postinstall.js
>
> Success! Netlify CLI has been installed!
>
> Your device is now configured to use Netlify CLI to deploy and manage
>   your Netlify sites.
>
> Next steps:
>
> netlify init     Connect or create a Netlify site from current
>   directory   netlify deploy   Deploy the latest changes to your Netlify
>   site
>
> For more information on the CLI run netlify help Or visit the docs at
>   https://cli.netlify.com
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2
>   (node_modules\netlify-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - netlify-cli@2.36.0 updated 1 package in 22.697s

However when I try doing *netlify*, I get the following respone:

> 'netlify' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I go to:

> C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netlify-cli

then it will work. However, I want to be deploying from other directories.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: did you try any of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955217/global-npm-package-installed-but-command-not-found ?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why netlify is not working anywhere else is because it is not being recognized as an environment variable. You need to add the path to the environment variable, close the git bash and then run the netlify command again.

To add the netlify path to the environment variable, follow these steps:

1. Search environment in the search box and choose **Edit the System environment variables**.

[image: Environment variable search]

2. Click on **Environment Variables...** from **System Properties** dialog box.

[image: Environment Variables]

3. In **System Variables** section, click on **Path** variable and click on **Edit**.

[image: Environment Variables dialog box]

4. In the **Edit Environment Variable** dialog box, click on **New** and add the path `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\` or `C:\Users\soyebp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\netlify-cli`, whichever works for you.

[image: Add path]

5. Close **git bash** and run it again. Now type `netlify` and it should work. It will show output similar to this:

[image: Netlify in git bash]

Answer (score 0):

Aditya's solution working nicely, just want to take a not, my npm global folder was at this path:

```
C:\.npm-global
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).