# How can I install angular?

Tags: angular, installation

I have installed the angular by: `npm install -g @angular/cli` and it has completed with this notification: `+ @angular/cli@9.1.5
added 271 packages from 206 contributors in 453.725s`.
But when I run to create a project by: `ng new my-app`, it returned this: `'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
Something was wrong with me? Help me to find that problem, thank you!

Comment: You ran the correct command.  The installation should be super easy.  I've run into a similar issue myself.  In my case reformatting the machine to like new status is the only thing that fixed it. I had homebrew and a bunch of dev stuff installed.  Who knows what was wrong? However, you should tag your OS.  You can try some simpler things like deleting/creating config files for bash (or whatever you are using)

Comment: That happens sometimes.Maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955217/global-npm-package-installed-but-command-not-found you can find an answer.