# Unable to create a Vue project, getting the error as " 'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA1UK.jpg)

Unable to create a Vue project, getting the error as " 'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
Please find the screenshot for more clarity. Please help. Don't know why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [adding the npm directory to your computers PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955218/15205180)
and after that try opening a new cmd window.

if it still doesn't work you can either restart your computed (for new env variables to take effect) or open the cmd from the npm bin directory (where "vue" is an executable)

Comment: thanks Liad, that helped :)

Comment: im glad, you're welcome :). please accept this answer so that people who enter this post will see it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Got it, thanks Liad :)