# Can not recognize dotenv while using dotenv -e .env.dev yarn dev in next.js project

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg, dotenv

I built a next.js project and installed dotenv through

```
yarn global add dotenv-cli
```

I also installed all the package with `yarn` and they were all installed successfully, but when I run:

```
dotenv -e .env.dev yarn dev
```

it returns:

```
dotenv : The term 'dotenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotenv -e .env.dev yarn dev
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dotenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix your [powershell path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955217/global-npm-package-installed-but-command-not-found) to use global NPM packages.

Also just to note, next.js [supports .env files](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) out of the box, so dotenv-cli shouldn't be needed unless you want to create .env files through the terminal.